# How could I replace the values from a dataframe column into another dataframe columns. Just like the image

Tags: python, string, dataframe, replace, data-cleaning

I want to replace unknown for new york, chicago for unknown. I mean I want to replace all the values that match with the string 'unknown' with the values of the other column and  vice versa. Any help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWJFP.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

[fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) is the function you need.
You first, replace the 'unknown' value by nan, then replace all nan by the other column value.

```py
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan

df = (
    pd.DataFrame(
        {
            'CITY_MULTIPLE_CHOICE': ['new york', 'chicago', 'unknown', 'Los Angeles'],
            'CITY_OPEN': ['unknown', 'unknown', 'Chicago', 'Chicago'],
        }
    ).replace('unknown', nan)
    .assign(
        CITY_MULTIPLE_CHOICE=lambda x: x.CITY_MULTIPLE_CHOICE.fillna(value=x.CITY_OPEN),
        CITY_OPEN=lambda x: x.CITY_OPEN.fillna(value=x.CITY_MULTIPLE_CHOICE)
    )
)
print(df)
```

With

```
  CITY_MULTIPLE_CHOICE CITY_OPEN
0             new york   unknown
1              chicago   unknown
2              unknown   Chicago
3          Los Angeles   Chicago
```

Previous code will print:

```
  CITY_MULTIPLE_CHOICE CITY_OPEN
0             new york  new york
1              chicago   chicago
2              Chicago   Chicago
3          Los Angeles   Chicago
```